# WinRar right click context menu issues

Tags: winrar

I have recently switched all be reluctantly to Windows 8 and when installing WinRar, the right click context menu features, (Extract here, add to, etc....) do not show up. I clicked the settings during install and also went in to options/settings/integration tab and it was checked. I tried unchecking and restarting and rechecking with no luck. Does this feature not work with Windows 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Windows 8 64-bit, make sure you installed WinRAR 64-bit as well. I suspect you installed the 32-bit version and the shell extension/content menu handler DLL is obviously not being loaded by the native 64-bit explorer.exe program.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That did seem to work. The only issue is I have an evaluation copy now. It says 40 day trial. I just hope it doesn't stop after the 40 and only adds nagging buy me screen.

Comment: So you bought and registered the app earlier? If so, just re-register it using your key, or copy your RarReg.key file to the WinRAR folder. Also, since you're new here, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Sorry, Didn't know I was supposed to accept. Done now. I must have typed something wrong before. I retried the key and it worked this time. I suffer from FFS (Fat Finger Syndrome) LOL. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: NP, was just pointing out how the site works. Glad you got it to work!